# Proving $\eqalign{n\choose k} = {n\choose k-1} \frac{n-k+1}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I want to prove that

$$\eqalign{n\choose k} = {n\choose k-1} \frac{n-k+1}{k}$$

So I can just write

$$\eqalign{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}} = {\frac{n!}{(n-(k-1))! \cdot(k-1)!}} \frac{n-k+1}{k}$$

$$\eqalign{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}} = {\frac{n!}{(n-k+1)! \cdot (k-1)!}} \frac{n-k+1}{k}$$

$$\eqalign{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}} = {\frac{n!}{(n-k)! \cdot (k-1)!}}$$

I think I did a mistake in the last line, because I cancelled $(n-k+1)!$ since $(n-k+1)! = (n-k+1) \cdot (n-k)!$

So, is my mistake that I cancelled faculty wrongly?

Comment: Right, so you do want to prove something that is true! But why do you start your "proof" by assuming your proposed conclusion?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If the OP argues this equality with a series of "if and only if" statements, and reaches some result that is tautologically true, or some result that can be easily proved/verified, what is wrong with that?

Comment: I see no "if and only if"s there :-(

Comment: If you are interested, here is something similary: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929019/show-nck-fracnn-k-cdotn-1ck/2929033#2929033

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is you forgot the $k$ on the denominator of the rightmost fraction, and somehow dropped the factorial sign on the $(k-1)$ in the final fraction.

Note that $k \cdot (k-1)! = k!$ and you will have verified the identity.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac {n!}{(n−k)!⋅k!} = \frac {n!(n-k+1)}{(n−k+1)!⋅(k−1)!k} $$

At this point you are done 
$$ = \frac {n!}{(n−k)!⋅k!}$$